# Is limit computable reals countable?

Tags: reference-request, computability

The set of computable real numbers is countable. But is the set of limit computable real numbers countable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every limit computable real number still needs to be given by some computation, and there are only countably many possible computations (Turing machines), indeed there are only countably many.